# Можно ли создать файл ctags для bare репозитория git без его распаковки?

Tags: git, ctags

Есть задача: «прикрутить» *ctags* к *web*-интерфейсу *kallithea* для *git*-сервера.

Интерфейс *kallithea* позволяет просматривать файлы для любой ветки, для любой ревизии.

Выходит, нужно как то сделать так, чтобы можно было использовать *ctags* без «распаковки» репозитория.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

> интерфейс позволяет просматривать файлы для любой ветки, для любой ревизии

совершенно верно: можно получить **содержимое** любого файла.

---

**пример** (внутри «голого» репозитория).

получаем список коммитов в ветке new:

```
$ git rev-list new
c8589eedc496ab39447c2b3db164fdd6975774b6
479c4f1c423c6399da50c015157f78598383b967
```

смотрим дерево файлов, которое изменялось первым из коммитов (он первый в списке, но последний по времени создания):

```
$ git ls-tree c858
100644 blob d9e5eed92e5f5f49d47162f45de0d3beb552c6ef    file
```

видим, что изменялся файл по имени `file`. смотрим его содержимое в этом дереве:

```
$ git show d9e5
2015-08-05 18:41
2015-08-05 18:44
```

да, действительно, таково содержимое этого файла после последнего коммита в ветку `new`.

---

**таким** образом вы можете получить содержимое каждого файла *по отдельности*.

а для работы `ctags`, насколько я понимаю, этого явно недостаточно: требуется *рабочий каталог*, со **всеми** файлами/каталогами **одновременно**.

---

**виртуальная файловая система**

но, возможно, вам подойдёт какая-нибудь из реализаций виртуальной файловой системы для навигации по git-репозиторию: [figfs](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cse400/CSE400_2008_2009/websites/grant/final.pdf), [git-fs](https://github.com/g2p/git-fs) или ещё что-нибудь в этом духе.

насколько такое решение сможет помочь в решении вашей задачи — судить не берусь. пробуйте! «опыт — сын ошибок трудных».

Comment: конечно, спасибо за развернутый ответ, но я решил задачу при помощи хуков.

Answer (score 0):

В общем задача решается при помощи хуков, на клиенте нужно установить хук
.git/hooks/pre-push, нужно просто поправить коммит перед отправкой, сгенерировав файл сtags и добавить его.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Работает из корня проекта

message=$(cat .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG)
cur_branch=$(grep -o "refs/heads/\w*" .git/HEAD)
revision=$(cat .git/$cur_branch)

ctags --language-force=c++ -R -o .tags/$revision 

git add .tags/$revision
git commit --amend -am $message
```

потом уже не сервере можно извлечь файл с тегами и работать с ним из фреймворка веб-интерфейса.

Comment: нет хук не тот, что нужен, потому что хеш коммита меняется и имя тег файла тоже, боюсь, может привести к неожиданным последствиям в самом рабочем дереве, либо это нужно делать на хуках, либо нет.